# Navigate to another page from a Kendo UI viewModel

Tags: ajax, mvvm, kendo-ui

I make a request to receive a authentication token. When it's ok, I would navigate to the index.html page (See below "NAVIGATE TO "index.html").

How can I do that?

I tried with: `var app = new kendo.mobile.Application() app.navigate("index.html");` but it will not work. I receive the following error:

*0x800a139e - Error in JavaScript: Your kendo mobile application element does not contain any direct child elements with data-role="view" attribute set. Make sure that you instantiate the mobile application using the correct container.*

Thank you

```
class LoginViewModel extends kendo.data.ObservableObject {
isVisible = true;
username: string = "";
password: string = ""; 
errorText: string = "";     

clickHandler: any = function (e) {
    var self = this;
    var data = { grant_type: "password", username: self.get("username"), password: self.get("password") };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        url: "/token",
        data: data
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) {            
        // Cache the access token in session storage.
        sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.access_token);   

        ***NAVIGATE TO "index.html"***

    }).fail(function (jqXHR: JQueryXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.set("errorText", jqXHR.status + ': ' + jqXHR.statusText)
        });
}

constructor() {
    super();
    super.init(this);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation is ok; you are receiving the error because the application container does not contain a `<div>` element with `data-role="view"` as immediate child.

You need to have something like :

```
<body>        
    <div data-role="view" ....></div>
</body>
```

And initialize your app

```
... = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body 
//or another jquery selector 
);
```